# Static class objects of the same class

Tags: java, static

I'm trying to create two static objects of class `Test`: **CAT** and **DOG**. I want them to be able to have different output int `talk()` method:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Hi");

    Test.DOG.talk();  //"I am a cat" output
  }
}

class Test  {
    public static Test DOG = new Test("I am a dog");
    public static Test CAT = new Test("I am a cat");

    public static String talkString;

    private Test(String text)  {
        talkString = text; 
  }

  public static void talk()  {
        System.out.println(talkString); 
  }
}
```

However the **CAT** object overwrites the `talkString` therefore the **DOG** can no longer use it. Is there a way around it, while keeping **DOG** and **CAT** static themselves?

Comment: `public static String talkString;` <-- remove the `static`.

Comment: @Andy Turner But then my code wouldn't be valid: the DOG and CAT would *require* an object, to use a `talkString`

Comment: So... perhaps remove another `static`?

Comment: @Andy Turner which one? I want DOG and CAT to remain static.

Comment: There are 5 statics in your code. I've said that one should be removed specifically. How long would it take you to try the other 4? (Tip: *read the duplicate* so that you can understand what you're actually doing; also try searching for the compiler error you get if you just remove the `static` on `talkString`)

Comment: @Andy Turner sovled it, thanks.